# Python header print one time for every time I run the script not each time

Tags: python, csv, header, export-to-csv

I would like my header be print only one time when the script will run every hour (I will use schedule of windows for that so don't be focus on the schedule) to collect new data under the old data.

My actual print :

[image: actual]

and I would like it be like this :

[image]

Here my code (who work)

Any idea ?

```
#Source : http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/docs?d=resources/code-samples
import urllib2
import json
import time
import csv
from datetime import datetime#set the time



f = urllib2.urlopen('http://api.wunderground.com/api/8d3b5d3fa03ddb6f/conditions/weather/q/China/Beijing.json')

now = datetime.now()
current_year = now.year
current_day = now.day
current_month = now.month
current_hour = now.hour
current_minute = now.minute
current_second = now.second

json_string = f.read()
parsed_json = json.loads(json_string)
locations = parsed_json.get('locations', 'Beijing')
temp_f = parsed_json['current_observation']['temp_f']
weather = parsed_json['current_observation']['weather']

#--- Open the file   + write on it ---

f = open('out.csv','a')
header = "Datetime,Location,Temperature,current_condition\n"
date = str(now.month) + "/" + str(now.day) +  "/" + str(now.year) + " " + str(now.hour)          + ":" + str(now.minute) + ":" + str(now.second)
f.write(header)
f.write(','.join([date,locations,str(temp_f),weather]))
f.write('\n')
f.close()
# --- And Close the file ---
```

Comment: Easy, only write the header once. You're curently writing it every time you run the script.

Comment: How can set the write of the Header only for the first time ? sorry little newbi on this,first time i try this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thoroughly apologize for the previous versions. There was a tiny detail that I was missing but I've fixed it now. Here's the correct code:

```
#--- Open the file   + write on it ---

f = open('out.csv','a')
prev_data = open('out.csv', 'r').read()

header = "Datetime,Location,Temperature,current_condition\n"

# Add a header only if the file is empty
if prev_data == '':
    f.write(header)

date = str(now.month) + "/" + str(now.day) +  "/" + str(now.year) + " " + str(now.hour)          + ":" + str(now.minute) + ":" + str(now.second)
f.write(','.join([date,locations,str(temp_f),weather]))
f.write('\n')
f.close()
# --- And Close the file ---
```

Comment: OP is running the script every hour. `write_header` will always be set to true upon running the script, solving nothing.

Comment: I thought that OP keeps the script running.

Comment: He says "the script will run every hour".

Comment: I thought it will fetch data every hour...anyways, fixed now.

Comment: yes **the first time** the script run it print the header but after one hour it update the data on a new line and keep the old data(like history) and etc etc every hour.any idea ?

Comment: I get `IOError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor`.

Comment: Hi Xaranke,I've got : **if header not in f.read(): IOerror:File not open for reading** :(

Comment: Downvote removed. You should consider 1) using the pythonic `with` statement to open files, and 2) only reading the first line instead of the entire contents when checking for the header.

Comment: @JoelCornett Yup, I realize that. However, in a previous thread OP mentioned that he was new to Python, so I wanted to mirror his code as closely as possible to help him understand.

Comment: Xaranke i tried you code with success ! yes i am new in python  (i just started 1 month ago),i understand the code you add but didn't came to my head to put this before. I am very thanks for your help on this and the time you spend for a little new guy who come in the world of programs :)

Comment: Little question what 'a' and 'r' do ? and why open twice the file ?

Comment: @Nardrek the 'a' flag adds to the file while the 'r' flag reads the content of the file. You don't have to do this, of course. You can go with Joel Cornett's answer and not read the file twice.

Comment: thanks for your time will take care of this you already helped me a lot

Answer (score 0):

Just check if the file exists and create a new file with a header if it doesn't:

```
import os

if os.path.exists(my_csv_file_path):
    header_exists = True
else:
    header_exists = False

with open(my_csv_file_path, "a+"):
    if not header_exists:
        write_header()

    write_row()
```